# Cannot read property 'length' of null error

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the error I'm getting for my code:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
   at countPositivesSumNegatives
        at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:179:21
    at Promise._execute
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    at new Promise
    at describe
            at Object.handleError
        at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext
```

The goal is to create a function that takes in a random array of numbers (input), and returns the number of positive numbers and the sum of the negative numbers. Everything works except for the error message I'm getting above, which is for a wrong values test, whatever that means

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) 
{
  let negSum = 0;
  let count = 0;
  let arr = [];

  for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
    if(input[i] > 0)
    { 
      count++;
    } 
    if (input[i] < 0) 
    { 
      negSum += input[i];
    }
    if (!input[i]) {
      negSum = negSum;
      count = count;
    }
  }

  arr.push(count,negSum);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reproducible by `countPositivesSumNegatives(null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have some automated tests being run against your code, and they are checking how you handle bad input.  Your code is not set up to handle anything other than the expected array of numbers, so it fails those tests.

You can solve that in a lot of ways, but something as simple as

```
if (input === null) {
    return 'Input invalid'; // or something like that
}
// put your for loop here
```

will do the trick.  Chances are, you may face more test cases with unexpected input that you'll need to handle.  I hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, we're supposed to return empty brackets if it's null. I added this, but I'm still failing 1/2 error tests. Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: Does it show you which tests are passing and which failing?  Are you still failing the test with `null` input, or is it failing on a different test?

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to add an extra " || input.length == 0;" thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As melpomene hinted, that type error is being thrown because you're attempting to call `.length` on a `null` object.

Since is coming out of a "wrong values test", it sounds like a test suite is being run against your solution and one of those tests is checking to see if you're handling bad `input`, which you're not, thus the error.

I would recommend doing some validation of `input` before jumping into processing it. Simply put an `if` block at the top that makes sure `input` is not `null` and is in fact an array of numbers.

I'm assuming you have instructions on what to do in case of invalid `input`? Maybe just return?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deal with null array..

Here is how to solve that ( check against null):

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    let negSum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    let arr = [];
    if (input != null) {

        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i] > 0) {
                count++;
            }
            if (input[i] < 0) {
                negSum += input[i];
            }
            if (!input[i]) {
                negSum = negSum;
                count = count;
            }
        }
    }
    arr.push(count, negSum);
    return arr;
}
```